# Adding VPN exception (allow protocol) to UFW firewall rules?

Tags: vpn, iptables, firewall, ufw, pptp

I'm having trouble at work in connecting to the work VPN while Firewall (UFW) is active. When i disable it "sudo ufw disable", there are no problems.

When it's on, when trying to connect I receive the following

```
Apr 14 09:57:59 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2105.983679] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=89 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13425 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:57:59 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2105.996395] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13426 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:58:02 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2109.042945] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13427 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:58:03 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2110.040506] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=89 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13428 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:58:05 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2112.061598] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13429 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:58:07 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2113.994401] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=89 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13430 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:58:08 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2115.012322] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13431 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:58:11 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2117.994069] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=89 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13432 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:58:11 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2118.017850] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13433 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:58:15 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2122.002641] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=89 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=13435 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 pppd[11718]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 pppd[11718]: Connection terminated.
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 NetworkManager[1620]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 NetworkManager[1620]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 pppd[11718]: Modem hangup
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 pptp[11722]: nm-pptp-service-11714 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 pptp[11722]: nm-pptp-service-11714 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 pptp[11731]: nm-pptp-service-11714 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 pptp[11731]: nm-pptp-service-11714 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 pptp[11731]: nm-pptp-service-11714 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 pppd[11718]: Exit.
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 NetworkManager[1620]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 NetworkManager[1620]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 NetworkManager[1620]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 NetworkManager[1620]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 NetworkManager[1620]: <info> Policy set 'eduroam' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 14 09:58:17 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 NetworkManager[1620]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Apr 14 09:58:22 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 NetworkManager[1620]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
Apr 14 09:58:24 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2130.359917] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.25 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=110 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=12127 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=38605 WINDOW=37 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 14 09:58:24 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2130.792401] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.25 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=110 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=12128 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=38605 WINDOW=37 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 14 09:58:24 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2131.268906] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.25 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=110 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=12129 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=38605 WINDOW=37 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 14 09:58:25 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2132.221763] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.25 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=110 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=12130 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=38605 WINDOW=37 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 14 09:58:27 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2134.125750] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.25 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=110 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=12131 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=38605 WINDOW=37 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 14 09:58:31 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [ 2137.937259] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=198.252.206.25 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=110 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=12132 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=38605 WINDOW=37 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

How can I add an exception?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PPTP vpn user `port 47` aka `GRE`. To allow this traffic edit `/etc/ufw/before.rules` and add at the end of file

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules
```

this

```
# gre
-A ufw-before-input -p 47 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -p 47 -j ACCEPT
```

Then disable, enable `ufw`

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

*EDIT 1*

Rules must placed in `/etc/ufw/before.rules` before segment `# drop INVALID packets ...`

then again

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've tried and yet I still receive the following:



`Apr 14 11:45:48 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [   61.326768] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=89 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=14890 PROTO=47`

Comment: Add rule `sudo ufw allow 161.53.97.58`, then restart laptop.

Comment: `ERROR: Could not find a profile matching '161.53.97.58`

Comment: Sorry. sudo ufw allow from 161.53.97.58. I forgot from bedore ip address in command

Comment: `Apr 15 08:37:38 gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70 kernel: [  171.662902] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b4:6d:83:e4:ce:8d:00:22:19:6b:e0:22:08:00 SRC=161.53.97.58 DST=10.111.100.55 LEN=93 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=170 PROTO=47`

Still getting the firewall block. Maybe there's a range of IP addresses or gateways?

Comment: You have my *Edit 1*

Comment: Try `ufw allow 47/tcp`

Comment: `GRE` use `udp` for transport not `tcp`

Comment: Try reseting ufw rules `ufw reset` and add rules again

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as Mookey but I can confirm that the solution by 2707974 is working for me!

Let's see this step by step.

If have Gufw set to incomming:deny and outgoing:allow with logging on.
Then if I switch VPN on, the first contact to my VPN provider is allowed normally without any rules. When the VPN provider is calling back his call is blocked.

> [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT=
>   MAC=49:........:10 **SRC=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy**
>   DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=49 ID=33716 **PROTO=47**

x = me, y = my vpn provider.

It is blocked by a combination of reasons, incoming ip and protocol 47.

Now, when turn Gufw off again and start the vpn.
`netstat -nautp` sees:

> tcp 0  0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50798    yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:1723 ESTABLISHED -

EDIT 1 of 2707974 is correct but and must be inserted at exact that place.
This would take care of the protocol 47 being allowed.
After that you can add a rule to allow the incoming connection of your vpn proveder. You can use: `sudo ufw allow yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy` and it is working.
You can even include ports (when you are sure they are not picked random)

`sudo insert 1 allow from yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy port 1723 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 50798`

That works too.
You might think that you are settled now, but there one security concern.
The protocol 47 rule is processed much earlier than the allow ip rule.
As soon as there is an incoming packet of protocol 47 it is allowed. There is no rejecting if the ip address does not fit.

You can see happening when you delete the ip rule from ufw.
`sudo ufw delete 1` (do not forget to disable/enable ufw again)
VPN will still be working.

I'm very sure you do not want every packet of every host coming into your system only because it is of GRE protocol. More secure is to include the IP of your VPN provider so he is the only one.

Change EDIT 1 into:

```
-A ufw-before-input -p 47 -s <your vpn provider> -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -p 47 -s <your vpn provider> -j ACCEPT
```

This is working and is secure. You can verify this your self by changing the ip above to an incorrect ip and vpn stops working.
The Gufw rule is not needed anymore although this was what my intension was. I would appreciate a working Gufw rule much more.

Hope it helped you.
Cheers!

Comment: Will try first thing tomorrow at work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Iptables, maybe there are some rules that aswell block your VPN connection.

```
iptables -L
```

`ACCEPT` VPN connections for `INPUT` aswell to `OUTPUT` at Iptables.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 47 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 47 -j ACCEPT
```

If VPN connection works, then save rules

```
iptables-save
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have no idea what the problem is. Anyway, thank you guys for the effort, I'll just use it with firewall disabled when I'm at work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally found a good way:

1. Create a rule to allow incoming traffic on 1723 port only form the VPN at IP xx.xx.xx.xx:

   ```bash
   sudo ufw allow from xx.xx.xx.xx to any port 1723
   ```
2. Create a rule to allow incoming GRE traffic only form the VPN at IP xx.xx.xx.xx:

   ```bash
   sudo ufw allow from xx.xx.xx.xx proto gre
   ```
3. If needed restart UWF

   ```bash
   sudo ufw reload
   ```

In this way ufw manage iptable or nftables for you

*note :* You can replace 'xx.xx.xx.xx' by 'any' if you want a less secure rule allowing any ip to connect to your computer.